# Optimal strategy for covering all possible subsets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was playing a game, and I started wondering about this:

> In the game Little Inferno, there are lots of items, and burning a particular subset of them gives you a combo. The "Deadly Vices" combo in particular is tricky to get, and is made up of 3 items. You're out of ideas on how to get the combo, so you want to try and get the combo by burning items systematically.
>
> There are 120 possible items which could be a part of the Deadly Vices combo. To prevent the game from lagging, you're allowed to burn n items at a time. You want to minimise your number of tries in the worst case, meaning that you don't want much overlap in the subsets you choose.
>
> What is the least number of burnings that will guarantee you the Deadly Vices combo and how would you achieve the optimal strategy?

Of course, the cases $n < 3$, $n = 3$ and $n >= 120$ are all trivial. Also, an obvious lower bound can be found by noting that there are $120 \choose 3$ possible combos, and since you can cover $n \choose 3$ at a time you'll need at least $\lceil {120 \choose 3} \div {n \choose 3} \rceil$ tries.

However, I'm not sure what to do about the cases in between. For example, if you had only $5$ items, and $n = 4$, then some overlap is guaranteed. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, but this is appears to be an open problem in combinatorics known as the Covering Design problem.  See http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/covering_designs

Comment: Thanks for the link - it'll be easier to research online now that I know what the problem is called :)

Comment: A good resource for covering designs is [the La Jolla Covering Repository](http://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html) maintained by Dan Gordon.  A survey of constructions and bounds is [here](http://www.ccrwest.org/cover/cover.pdf), describing in particular the Schönheim lower bound on the smallest size of a  $(v,k,t)$ covering.  Unfortunately the designs they have are limited to fewer than 100 points (and you ask about 120 items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a quite hard open problem, I think I'll just answer this and say that based off the Covering Repository (see hardmath's comment), for $n = 15$ (a rough guess at the game's limitations) at least 500 burning attempts will have to be made. While it's not an exact answer, it's a good enough lower bound for my purposes.